# new Android Eclipse SDK project properties window missing "Java compiler > annotation processing" tab

Tags: android, eclipse

maybe someone also came across the strange issue. I've updated last week my android Eclipse SDK (fresh installation) and noticed that project properties window is now missing `Java compiler > annotation processing` tab. I am working on mac. And it's the Eclipse Juno Version: 4.2.1.v20130118-173121-9MF7GHYdG0B5kx4E_SkfZV-1mNjVATf67ZAb7
Build id: M20130204-1200

Does somebody know how to bring it back? Or how to download proper version of sdk.

Comment: when u updated annotaions.jar mite be deleted ,get annotation.jar (2kb file) , and paste in this location C:\android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140624\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140624\sdk\tools\support\

Comment: U should be right, thanks for the idea. I will check it out on monday.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The reason:

It seems that entire `apt` plugin is missing in latest version of Eclipse ADT

In previous `20140624` version: `apt` and annotation files were available:
[image]

But in latest `20140702` version: all `apt` files are missing:
[image]

### Solution:

The only solution so far is to download a standard version of [Eclipse IDE](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) and install [ADT plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) separately from repository:
`https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/`

But according to the official Android Issue Tracker: [Issue #73798](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73798) - this issue should be resolved in next release of ADT bundle.

> Should be in 23.0.3 bundle
>
> https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/102240/

Comment: ..And this is why you should never immediately update Android Studio, the SDK or the ADT plugin without waiting to see if people run into issues. They always break something.

Comment: Yeah, there can always be a surprise with that:) But this one is not for updating, but rather while downloading a new Eclipse ADT bundle from website. Normally (if you already have Eclipse ADT working) you would just update the ADT plugin alone and everything wwould work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Maciej Ciemięga gave a clue to work this out. But you may not need to install a previous version at all. Instead you just need to download these jar files:

1. org.eclipse.jdt.annotation_***.jar
2. org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core_***.jar
3. org.eclipse.jdt.apt.pluggable.core_***.jar
4. org.eclipse.jdt.apt.ui_***.jar

I found these files on my colleague's eclipse installation under Windows.

And place them in plugins directory of your ellipse root directory. Restart your eclipse and you'll find Annotation Processing section under Java Compiler!

Comment: Well, I downloaded standard Eclipse Kepler and installed Android plugin. Works good.