# Can't add new activities with AndroidAnnotations

Tags: android, android-annotations

I'm using AndroidAnnotations framework in a project, and for some reason, when I add a new activity the framework does not generate the compiled activity (MyActivity_). It used to work fine until now and I didn't change anything. Juse created a new activity with the @EActivity annotation, and nothing got generated. Tried building/cleaning the project. Nothing works.
Using Eclipse.

Comment: Your question is not specific enough. What IDE are you using? What build system are you using?

Comment: @LukaCiko Using Eclipse. Regular build system (not sure how it's called), no gradle. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an investigation I realized that I don't my project menu doesn't have "Annotation Proccesing" under "Java compiler" (Project -> Properties -> Java compiler -> Annotation Proccesing) because a bug in the ADT version. Had to install Eclipse seperatly and then add the plugin, like it was suggested [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24897768/2463875).